# Get arguments from conditional type that spreads a tuple

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following piece of code

```js
class MyClass<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>> {

    constructor(private readonly entity: T) {
    }

    doStuff<K extends keyof T>(/* in a sec */): void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Given the following object, just as an example,

```js
const testEntity = {
  f1: () => 'test',
  f2: (a: string, b: number) => `${ a }:${ b }`
};
```

I want to be able to write

```js
const myClass = new MyClass(testEntity);

myClass.doStuff('f1');
myClass.doStuff('f1', { config: 'test' });

myClass.doStuff('f2', 'abc', 123);
myClass.doStuff('f2', 'abc', 123, { config: 'test' });
```

I was able to achieve it with the following code for the arguments

```js
doStuff<K extends keyof T>(key: K, ...args: [...params: Parameters<T[K]>, config?: Config]): void {
    // ...
}
```

But now inside the `doStuff` method I can't figure out how to get the props correctly.
I only have access to `key`, other than that I don't know how to get `params` (if they exist) and how to get `config` (if it exists as well).

Please check the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwChkTkFNscB+ALmQGcwpQcBuY0gW3Sggy1y1kIAK6cARtHYBfQoQQAbOPXrIAsgE9USlQB4AKsggAPSCAAmqgEoRyUc7oDWEDehjJ9AGmQAKAHQBcFA49HRwIBoAlMgAvAB8yOEacQlEHCTkIIxQIghgPD4ADswAbnCQyLxw5pgKGkbgwGAadPrRRKTIsunINQDKYCIwMLoA0kamEBaqzq7u+nE+s3Sj3gF+QSF0ANrrhUFwnKHIAAoHnBCQUPQG26MAunHemZRC-JT3kXQl6MDmBHJOrJuplGMhIIwAKKNZqxAGdGAARjoPmi8WQAHIIWAMZ4ejAAEwouB0bIsbziOiiCTQNEJAAGABJ8HBpDRmeJpPTCNJ2PJMGDOFodKoYsIIAB3dTC5T0HzY6FgJpRPlC7Syvz9QbDHwYpEYyLsNUizXoAZDGC6-XefBkCi4OhYiCMDFdQ1yY0arUWq0E3GYuDiBD+xEEgDM7s9KlN5p1er93gxgeD3lDYZtdoEOEd2Nd0ndhCAA) with the above code.

I'm not sure if there'd be a way for getting that or if I'd need to change the definition.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind including TKey and TParameters? I can't run your code without them.

Comment: @ddastrodd I added the types, as well as the Playground link with all the code that I have.

Comment: Your definition is probably more complicated than it needs to be (there's no reason to special-case `[]`, you can spread that just as well).  Can we simplify things in this question to just [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wRl1Em)?  If so, then we can focus on your issue, which I think is unsolvable, since you don't know whether a method of `T` happens to accept `Config` as its last parameter (and `Config` doesn't even have any required properties), so there's no way to distinguish.  Like, in practice, how would you imagine doing it? But first please help simplify the question as shown above.

Comment: @jcalz that is a very good simplification that I didn't see, thanks for that. About the real issue: I guess you're right. Since posting the issue I've thought of getting the length of the Parameters tuple and what not. I didn't want to change how you're supposed to call the method, but I guess I'll have to.

Comment: So can you [edit] the question to use the simplified example?  Then I can answer it (with either [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5zpN) which is fragile or [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqk0Rw) which is less fragile)